# How to pool cells while keeping the old cells intact?

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I want to create an n x 1 cell array, based on an n x m cell array. I want to operate on each row of the n x m cell array, so that all the cells will be put into a single cell in the new array. 
e.g. the old one is like this

```
{'a'}, {'bc'}, {'def'}, {'g'}
{'h'}, {'i'}, {'jk'}, {'lmn'}
```

the new one is like this

```
{1x4 cell}
{1x4 cell}
```

Inside the 1st {1x4 cell}, there are 4 cells 
`{'a'}, {'bc'}, {'def'}, {'g'}` and so on. How to do it?
I don't want to merge cells so that it becomes `{'abcdefg'}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your input is a 2D cell array of strings,

```
c = {'a', 'bc', 'def', 'g';
     'h', 'i',  'jk',  'lmn'};
```

the desired output is given by [`mat2cell`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html) (inspite of that function's name, its first input can be any array, not necessarily a matrix):

```
result = mat2cell(c, ones(1,size(c,1)), size(c,2));
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is not necessarily the shortest, but is intended to be very easy to understand.

```
% define your NxM cell array
%  it is 2x4
x = [{'a'}, {'bc'}, {'def'}, {'g'} ; ...
     {'h'}, {'i'}, {'jk'}, {'lmn'} ]

% number of rows for the cell array
numRows = size(x,1);

% preallocate the output
y = cell(numRows, 1);

% iterate over each row
for k = 1 : numRows
    % get one row of the cell array
    y{k} = x(1,:)

end
```

Comment: The first one is understandable to me and simpler. I accepted the first answer. But thanks anyway!